# Compress AVI File

Tags: compression, directshow

I am trying to compress an AVI file using Visual Basic 6.0 but having trouble finding out information on how I can do this.

I am aware that I may be able to use direct show and use the File Source, AVI Compressor and File Writer filters but in quick tests I have not been able to get the Pins of the Filters to Connect.

Is there any other simple mmethod of achieving this such as a DLL?

Thanks/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an AVI file, you can go

```
AVI File -> AVI SPlitter -> (compressor/encoder like ffdshow video encoder) -> AVI Mux -> File writer
```

turned a 2.16gb avi into a 5.56mb avi

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you mean compress? Your question lack information but I think you want to convert the file using [ffmpeg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ffmpeg)/libav to another format.

Comment: Yes am sure that I want to compress it, I am trying to use Direct Show currently using a avi file source, Microsoft H.263 Video Codec and File Writer filters but I am unable to connect them together so I was wondering if there was any sample code or pre-compiled dll's  that provide this functionality.

Comment: That's not strictly file compression, you need to understand the differences between compressing a file and encoding the data using a different codec. The link I gave you provides the answer.